# MongoDB only removing first field from the collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm a beginner in MongoDb.I wanted to know what is the query to remove a field in Mongo DB Collection.I have tried with

```
db.Component.update({},{$unset: {vendor:""}}).
```

Its was updating only first document.So How to remove field Completely from Collection?

Comment: Add `{ "muti": true}` as third argument object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-`db.Component.update({},{$unset: {vendor:""}},false,true)`
Here false

Comment: Here false means if specified field does not exist $unset will do nothing and true is apply to multiple Documents